# Simple Complex Dilation

Tags: complex-analysis

If $a>0$ and $$w = f(z) = az \text{, where }(a,z)\in \mathbb{C}$$ how is it that, in general, $$|w| = a|z|, Arg(w) = Arg(z)$$

It's written in my teacher's notes. Why do w and z have to like on the same ray? I thought multiplying complex numbers meant multiplying moduli and adding the args.

Comment: Here $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Actually writing $a>0$ implies that $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Now it should be obvious why the two properties hold.

Comment: Yes, $a>0$ implies $a\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score -1):

Multiplying complex numbers *does* scale the moduli and add the arguments. But the argument of a positive real number is $0$. Hence Multiplying *any* complex number by a positive real will only scale it, while keeping it on the same ray (i.e. argument).